# How to update azure iot edge modules from Azure IoT Central?

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-central

How to trigger updates of Azure IoT edge Modules from IoT Central? During device template definition "Deployment Manifest" json is uploaded for first time ,how to update /replace manifest for updating /installing newer versions of Edge Module from IoT Central ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update an IoT Edge module in IoT Central (for instance update the Docker image), you need to take the following steps:

1. Take the original deployment manifest you created and make your desired changes (such as updating the Docker image.
2. Go to the Device Template.
3. Hit Version in the menu bar.
   [image: Version button]
4. Choose a new name for your upgraded template.
5. Hit Replace Manifest in the menu bar and upload your new manifest.
   [image: Replace manifest button]
6. Publish your new device template.
7. In your list of devices, select the device and choose migrate.
   [image: Migrate button]
8. Select your new device template. It will be migrated to your new device template, including the changes.